MSIX not copying resource file correctly
I have a program with the gdal package that i want to include in the MSIX installer.
before updating to .net8 it worked with the structure
-WindowsApps
--Appx_hash
---gdal
---images
---myAppX

but somehow with the new architecture it is expecting gdal to be inside the myAppX folder.
I dont know how i can do this. In the build it is inside the folder, but once i publish it, it has a different folder structure.
I added it in the solution explorer as a folder, i said its content and should be copied everytime... anyone know what the issue could be?
